# Solving certificate errors when uploading to artifactory with twine in corporate environment

Tags: ssl, artifactory, twine

I want to upload a Python package to a secured (HTTPS) Artifactory server from my machine using Twine.

First, using the following:

```
twine upload --verbose \
--repository-url https://URL/artifactory/api/pypi/PATH \
--username XX \
--password XX \
dist/*
```

I get the following error:

```
requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='URL', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /artifactory/api/pypi/PATH (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1108)')))
```

After a big of digging, I found [this little solution](https://github.com/pypa/twine/issues/387#issuecomment-556905605). So I downloaded the cert.pem file and provided it to my upload command with:

```
--cert ../../bin/cert.pem
```

Which still gives me the following error:

```
certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate
```

How can I solve this issue correctly (I would like **NOT TO** disable SSL check).

Answer (score 1):

I should have searched a bit more. Here is the answer (for my self me in the future most likely).

You need a PEM file containing all the certificate chain (if applicable) of the server you want to contact. In my question, I downloaded only the end certificate, missing the root and intermediate one.

To achieve this, a manual option is to download all certificates from the browser (you can find plenty of examples on Internet on how to do that, like, for example, [this one for Edge](https://customer.precisely.com/s/article/Exporting-an-SSL-certificate-via-your-web-browser-360022585973?language=en_US)). You may find several nodes in the tree, download all of them.

After this is done, concatenate the certificates into one file, which would look like:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
THE KEY
BLABLA
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
THE OTHER KEY
BLABLA
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

If you had to download N certificates, you should have N sections in your unique file.

THen, pass that file to the command line:

```
--cert my_file_with_all_the_certificates
```

Comment: In my use case, I had to download the Zscaler VPN certificate `zscaler.pem` and append the certificate to the Microsoft SDK Python folder (on windows at `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\CLI2\Lib\site-packages\certifi\cacert.pem`).

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be an issue with the client in recognizing the certificate. Are you trying to execute the above mentioned task in a MacOS machine? If yes, installing **Certificates.command** should help resolving this issue.

**How?**
Go to the Applications folder in the system, select the appropriate Python installation directory and double click on Certificates.command file.